# HTML file dosent work when it is saved as php and using any php code

Tags: php, html

I designed my web page using ms office frontpage 2003 as I am little bit familiar with that.Later I saved that using php extension as I want to use more php code in there.But soon after i include any php code it only shows the HTML code in the browser.

Your kind consideration given with this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: The browser should only show the HTML code

Comment: if you donot have apache running then the browser will treat all code as plain text .. try installing xampp or wampp

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.It is.I havent started the wampp server from the morning.Thank you very much.Its fine now.Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be confused about how PHP and HTML work.

Feel free to use whatever text editor you wish, but PHP code will not show up in the browser. This is the intended behavior. PHP is executed server side, and therefore it is completely invisible to the eyes of the clients (browsers.) If you're not using a server with PHP installed, then your PHP code wont execute, obviously, but under no circumstances should you see PHP code in your browser.

Answer (score -2):

Use an editor like Notpad++ (notepad-plus-plus.org), Editpad Pro (www.editpadpro.com) sublime text (www.sublimetext.com) etc. to edit your html files. Go ahead open your .html or .php files in these editors and make appropriate changes.

**UPDATE:** PHP scripts run on web server. You cannot just open .php files in browser like .html files. For PHP scripts to execute you need to have a web server. Install XAMPP in your system. https://www.apachefriends.org